# Create an API Gateway using a terrafom module for multiple resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, terraform

I'm trying to build a `terraform` module for an `api gateway` but I have no idea how to use it for multiple resources.

I tried like this:

```
module "api1" {
  source = "../apigateway"
  path="path1"
  method="GET"
}

module "api2" {
  source = "../apigateway"
  path="path2"
  method="POST"
}
```

But doing like this I end up with 2 api gateway instead of one with 2 resources.
I have no idea how to do it.
Any idea ?

Thanks.

C.C.

Comment: did you add several resource `aws_api_gateway_method` to the api gateway?

Comment: No, but I would like to be a module for one or several methods, a generic module.

Comment: I would suggest against trying to create a generic API Gateway module because the complexity will either make it very inflexible and so useless or very open and then being a pointless layer in front of just using the resource. I'd only suggest creating a module in front of a set of API Gateway resources if you had a strict scope for it and had a very small amount of stuff you want to expose variably.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a set(map)  input that will get several of parameters and then you will be able to create the module dynamically for each object in the array